# Finding joint pdf of two random variables.

Tags: probability

We are given the probability distribution function (PDF) of the random variable $X$ $f_X (x) = 0.5 \big( u(x+1)-u(x-1) \big)$ and another random variable $Y$ is given as $Y=X^2$. We can find the PDF of $Y$ by using a transformation. We are asked to find the coefficient of correlation of $X$ and $Y$, which can be found using the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ $f_{X \space Y} (x,y)$ but how can we find the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Your description of this problem is not very clear.  What information are you given exactly?

Comment: The joint PDF of (X,Y) does not exist.

Comment: 3 minutes. *Ottimo!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to find the joint PDF since
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)
&=\operatorname{Cov}(X,X^2)\\
&=\operatorname E[(X-\operatorname EX)(X^2-\operatorname EX^2)]\\
&=\operatorname EX^3-\operatorname EX\operatorname EX^2-\operatorname EX^2\operatorname EX+\operatorname EX\operatorname EX^2\\
&=\operatorname EX^3-\operatorname EX\operatorname EX^2.
\end{align*}
We need to evaluate $\operatorname EX$, $\operatorname EX^2$, $\operatorname EX^3$ and $\operatorname EX^4$ (we need the fourth moment to calculate the variance of $X^2$).

Comment: thanks for your response but how can we evaluate it without joint PDF

Comment: @SelmanHassen You wrote that you have the PDF of the random variable $X$. You can calculate $\operatorname EX^k$ for $k=1,2,3,4$ with this PDF. We have that
$$
\operatorname EX^k=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^kf_X(x)\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: can you show me the steps

Comment: @SelmanHassen You just need to evaluate the integral in my previous comment (you can use [Integral Calculator](http://integrals.wolfram.com/)).